# How to install a custom library written in C?

Tags: 14.04, c

I want to install  Stanford Portable Library on my system (Ubuntu 14.04). Can anyone please instruct me how to do it?

Comment: @Eliah Kagan do u know how to install thelibrary? or are u here to correct grammatical errors in the questions?

Comment: May be this thread have  a look at this http://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/how-to-install-spl-libraries-in-ubuntu.

Comment: @Hunter I'm not sure: I *think* I do know how, I'm working on an answer right now, and I'm testing the procedure in my answer to make sure it is really correct (or at least so it's less likely to be wrong).  Of course this will only be helpful if I correctly understand *what* library you need to install. Btw, please note that my edit added significant information to your post, as well as attempting to make it clearer. Improving grammar was not one of my goals, though even if it had been [that would have been considered appropriate](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install the C-based [CS50 fork](https://github.com/cs50/spl) of the Stanford Portable Library, you can install it by running these commands in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```bash
# Install build dependencies and set up /usr/local/src for administrators.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-7-jdk git
cd /usr/local/src && sudo chgrp sudo . && sudo chmod g+w,+t .

# Retrieve, configure, build, test, and install the library.
git clone git://github.com/cs50/spl.git && cd spl
make SHELL=/bin/bash
build/tests/TestStanfordCSLib
sudo make SHELL=/bin/bash install
```

`SHELL=/bin/bash` is required, at least for the `make install` step, because the `Makefile` uses a feature present in [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) ([brace expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)) but not present in [Ubuntu's default `/bin/sh`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) (which is [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dash.1.html)).

- Running `sudo make install` instead of `sudo make SHELL=/bin/bash install` will produce the error:

  ```
  cp: cannot stat ‘build/lib/{libcs.a,spl.jar}’: No such file or directory
  Makefile:320: recipe for target 'install' failed
  ```
- In [the build instructions](https://github.com/cs50/spl/blob/master/README.md), which as of the time of this writing have not been updated with a procedure for Ubuntu, Fedora users are instructed to run `sudo make install`. *That works on Fedora*, but not Ubuntu, because Fedora's `/bin/sh` *is* provided by `bash`.

Once you have successfully built and installed the library using those steps, two new files will exist in `/usr/local/lib`: `libcs.a` and `spl.jar`. To use the library from C programs, link to `libcs.a`.

---

If you want to install [The Stanford Portable Library for C++](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/), you can do that by running *these* commands in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```bash
# Install build dependencies and set up /usr/local/src for administrators.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-7-jdk
cd /usr/local/src && sudo chgrp sudo . && sudo chmod g+w,+t .

# Retrieve, configure, build, and test the library.
wget https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/StanfordCPPLib/cpplib.zip
unzip cpplib.zip && cd cpplib
make
./TestStanfordCPPLib
```

This procedure worked for me, and the test executable ran successfully. See the contents of the `README` file in the `cpplib` archive for additional information. Often to build software from source there is a `./configure` step before running `make`; the `README` clarifies that, to build this software, one simply runs `make`.

Assuming `make` succeeded, it created:

- a statically linkable `.a` library file, `lib/libStanfordCPPLib.a`, which is *probably* what you will link into your programs
- statically linkable object files in the `obj` subdirectory of `cpplib`

Besides linking against the `.a` file (as one might usually do), it appears one way to use the library is to link against these `.o` files with your programs. The contents of `Makefile`, particularly under `# Test program`, show how to do this.

The `.a` file appears to have all these `.o` files linked into it, though, so you should not have to use the individual `.o` files unless you prefer to do so or need to produce an especially small statically linked executable.

(If you need to build a shared library--i.e., an `.so` file--rather than a static one, I suggest editing your question to add information about that. I don't know how to build cpplib in this way, but others may be able to answer that.)

Comment: I want to install Stanford Portable Library for c not c++

Comment: @Hunter Oh. Is [the CS50 fork](https://github.com/cs50/spl) what you're trying to install? Or some other version?

Comment: yes! now u got it !

Comment: @Hunter I've expanded my answer to cover installing the CS50 fork of SPL. Hopefully this will help.